# Exporting Access Table into XML using VBA

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access

I have an Access Table that was originally imported from XML.  When I export it I do not have the same XML structure as the original XML table.

The original imported table looks as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>
<profiling>
  <program>
    <name>118CDSpro</name>
    <p1on>1</p1on>
    <p1tool>36</p1tool>
    <p2on>OFF</p2on>
    <cut>OFF</cut>
    <rule>OFF</rule>
    <desc>118 Clad DirectSet Profile</desc>
    <pic>akv.bmp</pic>
    <ten>dilec_F</ten>
  </program>
<profiling/>
```

This is what I get in an export:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot generated="2016-06-27T12:16:29" xmlns:od="urn:schemas microsoft-com:officedata">
  <Profiling>
     <name>Din_C92S_pro2</name>
     <p1on>1</p1on>
     <p1tool>40</p1tool>
     <p2on>OFF</p2on>
     <cut>OFF</cut>
     <rule>OFF</rule>
     <desc>Inswing Door Sash Profile 2 (Storm)</desc>
     <ten>dilec_F</ten>
  </Profiling>
</dataroot>
```

I think the problem lies within an .xsl file, but I am new to VBA and am unsure of how it is used.

This code has to very specific as to the original format.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Option 2 Code:

```
Sub ProfileXML2()

    ' RAW XML EXPORT
    Application.ExportXML acExportTable, "Profiling", "C:\MyData\Crafter 0610\Crafter\MACHINE\SCHEMAS\ProfileExport.xml"


    ' TRANSFORM RAW XML (OPTION 2 - full XSLT processor)
    Dim xmlDoc As Object, xslDoc As Object, newDoc As Object

    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set xslDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set newDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\MyData\Crafter 0610\Crafter\MACHINE\SCHEMAS\ProfileExport.xml"
    xmlDoc.async = False

    xslDoc.Load "C:\MyData\Crafter 0610\Crafter\MACHINE\SCHEMAS\ProfilingSchema.xsl"
    xslDoc.async = False

    ' TRANSFORM SOURCE TO FINAL
    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\MyData\Crafter 0610\Crafter\DATA\ProfilingTest.xml"

    Set newDoc = Nothing
    Set xslDoc = Nothing
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no problem. MS Access does not retain the imported XML file structure. The output you receive is the standard template of tables or query output in XML format. But since your end use needs cannot accommodate this raw output, consider using [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML documents.

You can either run the XSLT with [Application.TransformXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844810.aspx) or with the [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759204(v=vs.85).aspx) library. Below VBA code shows both options. This XSLT is a special script as the first two template matches remove the namespace, *urn:schemas microsoft-com:officedata*, from output returning local element names.

**XSLT** script *(save as .xsl to be loaded in VBA)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dataroot">    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Profiling"/>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Profiling">
    <profiling>
      <program>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      </program>
    </profiling>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**VBA** script

```vb
Public Sub XMLHandle()

    ' RAW XML EXPORT
    Application.ExportXML acExportTable, "TableName", "C:\Path\To\Raw\Output.xml"

    ' TRANSFORM RAW XML (OPTION 1 - limited XSLT method)    
    Application.TransformXML "C:\Path\To\Raw\Output.xml", _
                             "C:\Path\To\XSLT\Transform.xsl", _
                             "C:\Path\To\Final\Output.xml"

    ' TRANSFORM RAW XML (OPTION 2 - full XSLT processor)
    Dim xmlDoc As Object, xslDoc As Object, newDoc As Object

    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set xslDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set newDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Raw\Output.xml"
    xmlDoc.async = False

    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLT\Transform.xsl"
    xslDoc.async = False

    ' TRANSFORM SOURCE TO FINAL
    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\Final\Output.xml"

    Set newDoc = Nothing
    Set xslDoc = Nothing
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<profiling>
    <program>
        <name>Din_C92S_pro2</name>
        <p1on>1</p1on>
        <p1tool>40</p1tool>
        <p2on>OFF</p2on>
        <cut>OFF</cut>
        <rule>OFF</rule>
        <desc>Inswing Door Sash Profile 2 (Storm)</desc>
        <ten>dilec_F</ten>
    </program>
</profiling>
```

Comment: I tested both and the first option worked great aside from the fact that there was no indentation, which I believe does not really affect an XML data table. The second option gave me an error saying "only one top level element is allowed in an XML document".  Doesn't really matter except for my own knowledge as the first option works great.

Comment: Great! Please accept if answer helped. Second option will indent properly. I cannot recreate that error. Be sure paths point to correct files.

Comment: I am still trying to navigate the difference between answers and comments.  I did add something to my original question regarding option 2 regarding there being something not coded correctly.

Comment: Do you still get the error? Does your xml look *exactly* like your posted snippet? Post first elements. Did you properly copy the .xsl script? To be clear, XSL *is* an XML file and follows same rules with open/ending tags. Finally what version of MS Access do you run? What Windows version?

Comment: I cut and pasted from your example and as far as I can tell they appear to be the same.  Option 1 works fine, option 2 returns a run time error that says "Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document".  I am running Access 2013 with Windows 10. I am not that concerned as I do have your solution.  I am just trying to educate myself as much as I can with regard to option 2.  I very much appreciate your help.